# One div visible and other hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am no expert on programing with jQuery but I have a little bit knowledge about the language, the thing is that I want one div to be visible and the other one hidden, as soon as you click the other div it should slide down and the first one should be hidden.

The bug is that if you press one div atm is messes up.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#link').click(function () {
            if ($('.todo-post').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#date-visible').slideUp("slow");
                $('#date-hidden').slideDown("slow");
                $('#tick-hidden').slideDown("slow");
                $('.todo-post').slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $('.todo-post').slideUp("slow");
                $('#date-hidden').slideUp("slow");
                $('#tick-hidden').slideUp("slow");
                $('#date-visible').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
    });
```

That's the code I'm using at the moment, It works for one div there is text everywhere if I add another div, it gets messy. I believe that the code can be re-made so it works properly but sadly I do not know how and I have been searching the web for a while now.

[LINK TO MY WEBSITE](http://afgamers.se/Stackoverflow/)

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, your HTML code is invalid. That's said, you could use slideToggle() method

Comment: As mentioned above, the docs http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#example-0 should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that our elements have position absolute so if you add this css it will work:

```
div.todo-avatar-date-hidden {
    position: static;
}
div.todo-tick {
    position: static;
}
div.todo-post {
    position: static;
}
```

Also you need to put it relatively near the bottom of your css or it will be overridden by the previous code so I advise to go to each element in the css that I have shown and removing the line that makes the element absolute

**Edit**

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    if($('#date-visible').is(':hidden')) {
        if(!($('#date-visible-2').is(':hidden'))) {
            $('#date-visible-2, #date-hidden-2, #tick-hidden-2, .todo-post-2').slideToggle("slow");
        }
    }
    $('#date-visible, #date-hidden, #tick-hidden, .todo-post').slideToggle("slow");
});
$('#link-2').on('click', function () {
    if($('#date-visible-2').is(':hidden')) {
        if(!($('#date-visible').is(':hidden'))) {
            $('#date-visible, #date-hidden, #tick-hidden, .todo-post').slideToggle("slow");
        }
    }
    $('#date-visible-2, #date-hidden-2, #tick-hidden-2, .todo-post-2').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with less code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#link').on('click', function () {
        $('#date-visible, #date-hidden, #tick-hidden, .todo-post').slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique, no two elements can have the same id in a same page. You are using same id like "date-visible" in your HTML page. Change them and then code accordingly.